# Is it possible to call commands between extensions in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For example, there are two VSCode extensions:

- `extension1` has registered command `exCommand1`
- `extension2` has registered command `exCommand2`

According to documentation, a VSCode extension can call commands
(ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api)

```
executeCommand<T>(command: string, ...rest: any[]): Thenable<T | undefined>
```

If API Doc is correct then

- `extension1` can call `exCommand2` provided by `extension2`
- `extension2` can call `exCommand1` provided by `extension1`

But, VSCode's extensions are lazily loaded, so how does one call a command from another extension that may not already be loaded?

Answer (score 29):

I know this is an old post, if you still have the same requirement or for others googling, this is how I have done it.

```javascript
var xmlExtension =  vscode.extensions.getExtension( 'DotJoshJohnson.xml' );

// is the ext loaded and ready?
if( xmlExtension.isActive == false ){
    xmlExtension.activate().then(
        function(){
            console.log( "Extension activated");
            // comment next line out for release
            findCommand(); 
            vscode.commands.executeCommand("xmlTools.formatAsXml");
        },
        function(){
            console.log( "Extension activation failed");
        }
    );   
} else {
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("xmlTools.formatAsXml");
}


// dev helper function to dump all the command identifiers to the console
// helps if you cannot find the command id on github.
var findCommand = function(){
    vscode.commands.getCommands(true).then( 
        function(cmds){
            console.log("fulfilled");
            console.log(cmd);
        },
        function() {
            console.log("failed");
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: A brief stumbling block for me was figuring out what exactly to pass to `vscode.extensions.getExtension()`. To get a list of extension IDs, you can use `vscode.extensions.all.map(x => x.id)`. They are of the form `<extension publisher>.<extension name>`.

Comment: I'm not the one that answered the question. You can try to pass them as a second parameter `vscode.commands.executeCommand("xmlTools.formatAsXml", HERE);` but no idea if it works between extensions.